# Proof that $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$ are Archimedean ordered fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, solution-verification, real-numbers

I searched for "archimedean ordered field" on this website and Google but didn't find much.

**Exercises:**

(pages 90 and 101 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher)

> [image]

> [image]

**My attempt:**

These exercises seem intuitively obvious, which makes me doubt that my proofs are rigorous. For the first exercise, I proceed as follows: if $b \leq 0$ then take $n = 1$; otherwise let $n$ be any integer larger than $\frac{b}{a}$. The proof for the second exercise works exactly the same way.

(I suppose both proofs rely on the fact that $\mathbb N$ is not bounded above in $\mathbb R$, which is proven on page 96.)

**Questions:**

What are these proofs lacking?

Intuitively, is the Archimedean property about the notion that there are no infinitely small positive quantities in $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb R$? Is this related to the historical discussions about "infinitesimals"?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: How do you know there is an $n$ bigger and than $b/a$? That is the whole point of the proof!

Comment: @TokenToucan This was proven on page 96. See the bracketed sentence.

Comment: Then there is no gap :)

Comment: How hard these proofs are depends on what you've proven about the reals already. As you say, intuitively the Archimedean property says that there are no infinitesimally small positive quantities (which is equivalent to saying that there are no infinitely *large* positive quantities), and you can use this idea to construct non-Archimedean ordered fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Archimedean_ordered_field